# PHPUnit não é reconhecido pelo CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, testes-de-unidade, phpunit

Agora com a descontinuação do suporte do PHPUnit pelo **Pear**, comecei a enfrentar um grande problema para fazer o CakePHP reconhecer o PHPUnit...

O PHPUnit já está instalado em meu computador (Linux Mint), consigo utiliza-lo pelo console sem problemas porém na hora de utilizar a API de testes do CakePHP não tenho sucesso.

Já tentei instalar pelo próprio composer, porém percebi que o conteúdo do PHPUnit vai para a pasta Vendor e tem uma divisão de pastas que realmente não entendo. Não sei se essa informação é relevante...

Quando acesso o arquivo test.php, para acessar os testes, os seguintes erros me são apresentados:

> Warning (2): include(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory
>   [CORE/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php, line 156]
>
> Warning (2): include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/var/www/html/sapekas/lib:/usr/lib/php:.')
>   [CORE/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php, line 156]

Procurei por toda internet de várias maneiras mas não encontrei solução. A grande maioria sempre falava para utilziar o **pear** para instalar o PHPUnit, porém ele não dá mais suporte para isso, então trata-se de um problema novo e acredito que seja por isso que ainda não existe muito material sobre como resolver

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o PHPUnit da sua própria aplicação que está dentro da pasta vendor. se você está utilizando o composer, tente o seguinte comando no console dentro da pasta do seu projeto:

/vendor/bin/phpunit

Comment: Como dito acima, eu consigo usar o PHPUnit perfeitamente pelo console, mas o meu problema é utilizar a API de testes do CakePHP através do arquivo test.php